# Accessing Audio Files in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, audio, aiff

I am attempting to link to audio files that exist on my server using the anchor tag. I am able to download and play the audio files just fine on Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but not on Internet Explorer. When I click the link in IE, all I see is a bunch of random characters. Also, when I attempt to download the audio file IE attempts to download it as an html file. What can I do to fix this so that I am able to access these files via IE.

Here is the code.

```
<a href="/audioFile.aif">audioFile.aif</a><br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that your server is not sending the correct `Content-Type` header. Make sure your server is configured to send the correct content type/MIME type:

```
audio/x-aiff
```